# (Python 3.6) Installing Numpy+MKL but the directory can't be located

Tags: python, file, numpy, directory, python-wheel

I couldn't get scikit-learn running for Python 3.6 and found out it was because I needed Numpy+MKL.

I uninstalled my previous versions of numpy, scipy and scikit-learn and then ran:

```
C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6>py -3 -m pip install C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

But got the following error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'C:\Users\Nick'
It looks like a path. Does it exist ?
```

I think this is because my USERNAME has a space in it, so I tried using quotes for the directory:

```
C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6>py -3 -m pip install "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.6\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
Requirement 'C:\\Users\\Nick Nagy\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.6\\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\nick nagy\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\python 3.6\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack_file_url
unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "C:\Users\Nick Nagy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in unzip_file
zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Nick Nagy\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Python 3.6\\numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl'
```

Comment: Can you navigate to the folder where the `.whl` file exists and type the same command - this time giving a relative path (which has no spaces)? This will at least confirm the theory of whether spaces are messing with this or not

Comment: Why are you installing from a local `.whl` file at all?  Why not just `pip install numpy`?

Comment: @JohnGordon does pip install numpy install Numpy+MKL?

Comment: @Nick I don't have any experience with that particular package.  I just know that's not the typical way to install pip packages.  You should try @Vivek's suggestion and cd to that directory and then just run `py -3 -m pip install numpy-1.13.3+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`, to rule out whether the directory name itself is the issue.